# Intercepting Registry changes

Tags: c#, winapi, hook, registry

I know that I can monitor registry changes using [RegNotifyChangeKeyValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724892.aspx). What I am wondering is if its possible to intercept and possibly prevent reading and writing to the registry. I know some virus programs, such as Norton Anti-Virus, will popup a warning, asking if its okay for some program to modify the registry, there for, I can only assume there must be a way to do this.

Preferably, I'd prefer a managed way, using C#, however, if anyone has any idea how to do this, even if its using some WINAPI function, I'll accept that answer too.

Thanks, in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Easyhook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/) - this is a managed version of an existing Microsoft Research project called Detours. This should do what you want.

Comment: Your answer is implying that Detours is outdated. This is not true. EasyHook is one option, Detours is another, and there are several other hooking mechanisms that can do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

A few years ago I did it on Windows XP by writing a driver (sys). On 32-bit version of Windows I found the table with function addresses and I replaced them with my own. Of course, the driver was calling the original registry API functions from the inside.

Don't know how it works on Vista/7 and x64 systems. Perhaps you will have to do some reasearch on that.

If you go this way, don't be surprised if some anti virus software reports your driver as malware.

Comment: Interesting way to go. What is this "table with function addresses" and how do I find them?

Comment: The table is actually a Service Descriptor Table (SDT). I will look for that code and give you some guidelines in a day or two. I know I have that driver somewhere. Until then, here is something that might help you: http://www.security.org.sg/code/sdtrestore.html As you can see, there is an exported symbol "KeServiceDescriptorTable", etc... I'll get back with some real answers on how to do it...